# Parse complex querystring in RESTful API

Tags: php, rest

I'm reading the seventh topic of [this](http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/) article where the author suggest to use the query string for filtering and sorting the container's resultset. So far so good, but:

Anybody knows for an PHP library that implement that kind of functionality?

The author use an especial syntax to do this:

> Use a unique query parameter for all fields or a query language for filtering.
>
> ```
>    GET /cars?color=red,blue Returns a list of red or blue cars
>    GET /cars?seats<=2 Returns a list of cars with a maximum of 2 seats
> ```
>
> Allow ascending and descending sorting over multiple fields.
>
> ```
>    GET /cars?sort=-manufactorer,+model
> ```

And so on.

Comment: what about parse_str() function?

Comment: You will already have it in the `$_GET[]` superglobal array.

Comment: Read the just-added quoted text from the linked article for more details about my question.